# rename columna base de datos

Tags: mysql, mariadb

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de modificar ciertos campos dentro de una base de datos, el problema se da con una tabla que tiene un campos con atributos en el nombre "dni / pasaporte ", cualquier tipo de cambio que realice marca error por este campo dentro de la tabla, he buscado como cambiarla mediante la consola pero me sigue dando error

He aqui lo que estoy intentando

`ALTER TABLE clientes RENAME COLUMN 'dni/pasaporte' TO 'identificacion';`

Y la respuesta de la base de datos

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '/nie/pasaporte TO identificacion' at line 1`

Estoy usando la version de MariaDB 15.1

Comment: ¿De verdad tienes un campo con una / en el nombre? Prueba a ponerlo entrecomillado con tildes a la izda.: \`dni/pasaporte\`

Comment: Si, es una base de datos que ya venia asi, ya habia intentado colocando las comillas simples en el nombre anterior y nuevo, pero me marca el mismo error

Comment: No son comillas simples (lo digo por si acaso). Prueba copiando y pegando la respuesta de Ernesto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas <kbd>`</kbd>

```
ALTER TABLE clientes RENAME COLUMN `dni/pasaporte` TO `identificacion`;
```

Comment: Vale si me funciono correctamente, error mio al querer pasar el comando con comillas simples, gracias de verdad